# How to filter on the props of the Record<K, T>

Tags: typescript, typescript-utility

Say I have this record:

```
export const MenuData: Record<Header, HeaderInfo> = {
  val1: {
    message: 'xyz',
    buttonText: 'txt',
    buttonUrl: '/url-abc',
  },
  val2: {
    message: 'xyz123',
    buttonText: 'txt4',
    buttonUrl: '/url-1abcd',
  },
  ... 
}
```

I want to `filter/find` the `MenuData` record based on `buttonUrl` property.
Something like `MenuData.filter(buttonUrl === '/url-1abcd')`
So in that case would return the whole `val2` object

Is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: Do you want just the key of the object?

Comment: @AsafAviv yeah I want the whole object (just updated the question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) on the object which will return an array of the values of the keys, then use `.find` to find the object you need based on the condition

```
const obj = Object.values(MenuData).find(obj => obj.buttonUrl === '/url-1abcd')
```

Comment: I like it, but - what would be a good way to return the original type Record<Header, HeaderInfo> rather than the array type.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
This is how I return key-value pairs for navigation.

##### 1. Keys

```js
export type PagePath =
  ...
  '/demos' |
  '/demos/hr-browser-scroll' |
  '/demos/grid/filter-management' |
  '/';
```

##### 2. Dictionary

```js
export const pagePath2PageInfoDict: Record<PagePath, PageInfo> = {
  ...
  '/demos': new PageInfo('demos'),
  '/demos/hr-browser-scroll': new PageInfo('demos', 'horizontal browser scroll'),
  '/demos/grid/filter-management': new PageInfo('demos', 'grids: filter management'),
  '/': new PageInfo(),
};
```

##### 3. Get key-value pairs

```js
export function getPagePath2PageInfoPairs(predicate: (path: string) => boolean = () => true) {
  return Object.keys(pagePath2PageInfoDict)
    .filter(predicate)
    .map(key => {
      const path = key as PagePath;
      const item: IPageNavItem = {
        path,
        info: pagePath2PageInfoDict[path],
      };

      return item;
    });
}
```

##### 4. Use

```js
export class DemosComponent extends PageCoreComponent {
  readonly navItems = getPagePath2PageInfoPairs(p => p.startsWith('/demos/'));
}
```

```html
<nav *ngFor="let navItem of navItems; index as i">
  <div class="nav-item"
       [routerLink]="navItem.path"
       routerLinkActive="active"
  >
    <div>{{ navItem.info.pageTitle }}</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image]